# Selenium and Python to Executable

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, executable

I have a Python script that I'm trying to convert to an executable so that other computers can use it without Python installed. I've been trying to use PyInstaller but I keep running into issues and I think its because I have the Selenium module installed. I found [this link from a couple months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853252/create-a-python-executable-with-chromedriver-selenium) and I tried following what the user did, except with Firefox and not Chrome, but my program still won't work as an executable. My program will end/crash when Firefox is supposed to open.

This is the .spec file I made following the answer in the post above, as well as the users comments that he claims worked:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Desktop\\Python'],
             binaries=[('C:\\Python\\browserdriver\\geckodriver.exe' , '.')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Work Bot v1.5',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
                a.binaries,
                a.zipfiles,
                a.datas,
                strip=False,
                upx=True,
                name='main')
```

Here are the relevant lines in my Python script:

```
path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "geckodriver")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(path)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

## EDIT:

After running the program in Command Prompt, I got to see the error before the program crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 404, in <module>
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 147, in __init__
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 78, in __init__
  File "shutil.py", line 309, in copytree
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Desktop\\Python\\dist\\main\\geckodriver'
[3056] Failed to execute script main
```

Comment: This is a single file or single dir bundle?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "geckodriver.exe")`

Comment: For some reason it produces the same result if I try to make it a single file or a single directory, if that's what you're asking. I'll try changing the path.

Comment: Did you try with `.exe` extension?