# Create a Python executable with Selenium webdriver manager

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, executable

I want to convert my Selenium code to an executable, I used auto-py-to-exe, it always worked for non Selenium codes, so I don't know what to do.

I was looking at the answer that was provided here :
[Create a Python executable with chromedriver & Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853252/create-a-python-executable-with-chromedriver-selenium)
but it doesn't exactly address my problem because you need to change the .spec file and add your Chromedriver path, but I don't use chromdriver, I use  webdriver manager.

so I am kinda lost here
any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck with same problem.
I thought to assume that selenium script as normal python file.
And it worked.
Steps to make it executable file:

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
```